# Excavator badge?

Tags: support, badges

I just noticed that I earned the "[Excavator](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/128/excavator)" badge a few minutes ago, putatively for a post that was "deleted or otherwise unavailable".  So, apparently, did dozens of other people.  I don't recall making any edits to old posts recently.  What's going on?

Comment: It's a new badge [just introduced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102400/archaeologist-badge-is-broken). Let's wait a little.

Comment: I agree with Grigory M.  I guess that when it is implemented correctly, however, it will be retroactive, so you will receive it if at some point in the past you edited a long unactive post.

Comment: ...and indeed it's fixed already.

Comment: @Grigory: Fixed, apparently... But I'm wondering why they removed the question you linked to (I haven't seen it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were some minor glitches in the intial awarding which caused people to earn multiple iterations of the badge (it's a one-time deal). Consequently, to handle this, we rolled out a fix that unawarded all of the badge instances, then re-awarded them afterwards. Getting the badge but having no associated question was probably an artifact from that process, but it is since no longer present.

You rightfully have the badge [attributed to this post edit last month](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548/explanation-of-method-for-showing-that-0-0-is-undefined/552#552), which was to a year-old post. It was only awarded recently, rather than at the date of the fact, because the badge was only just introduced.